Which script was the Torah given in at Sinai?
Background
Sifrei Torah today are written in kethav Ashurith, the Aramaic square script:

But this script is newer than "Paleo Hebrew"/Phonecian script, and historians say that the square script was adopted by the exiles in Assyria.
Question
What script was the Torah given in at Har Sinai?

I've been told by someone in a comment on this site that the script brought from Ashur was a "rediscovery", and indeed was the original. I would like to see more substantiation for that

See the whole story on Sanhedrin 21b.
